# Is there a limit for the number of PayPal subscriptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing, recurring

I am developing an application in Ruby on Rails in which it is important for customers to *create a custom* subscription plan according to their needs. With some simple math I calculated over 500 possible outcome prices for subscription plans. (Shipping, products, product quantity, etc).

I've searched in paypal's documentation but found nothing about a subscription quantity limit.

Is there any? Are there any other issues I might encounter by this approach of potentially having over 500 subscription plans?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

There is no limit in the official paypal documentation but 500 products in one session is too much - this is my opinion.

If you want to create multiple recurring profiles in a single Express Checkout session must implement PayPal Express Checkout API. Follow this steps ( with two recurring payments with example ):

- First you must Pass **all Profiles in SetExpressCheckout method**, for
  example:

> L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments
>
> L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=Tier 1

**and second product**

> L_BILLINGTYPE1=RecurringPayments
>
> L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION1=Management Services

- And then, after buyer has approved both in PayPal, **you need to call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile twice**:

**One sending "DESC" with the value "Tier 1" and another one sending "DESC" with the value "Management Services"**

[Also check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565213/paypal-express-checkout-api-is-there-a-way-to-process-both-recurring-payment-i)

Comment: Thank you for answering, I apologize for my poor explanation. I don't mean subscribing to 500 products at once. When subscribing a customer to a subscription plan, you have to first create a plan that indicates amount, name, and frequency of the plan. That plan is saved in paypal's developer dashboard.

 My question is about creating those plans dynamically and, therefor, having around 500 of those.